# Hamiltonians, density of state, BECs

Tags: definition, hamiltonian, bose-einstein-condensate

When working with Bose-Einstein condensates trapped in potentials, how can one tell what the density of state of a system of identical bosons given the Hamiltonian, $H$? (I have been told that it is possible.)

Suppose the Hamiltonian is some 2D harmonic oscillator -- so $$H=p^2/2m+(1/2)(a^2x^2+b^2y^2) \quad ?$$

I think there is some general formula, something like $$\rho(E)=[gV_dS_dp^{d-1}/(2\pi\hbar)^{d}] (dp/dE) \quad ,$$ where $d$ is the dimension of the space we are working in, $g=2s+1$ where $s$ is the spin of the particles and $V_d$ is the $d-$dimensional "volume", so for a fixed volume box, this is the volume of the box.

But what is $V_d$ in this case? And is $p$ simply $$p^2=2m[E-(1/2)(a^2x^2+b^2y^2)] \quad ?$$

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible. A good resource is this [statistical physics script](http://www.kroha.uni-bonn.de/teaching/lecture-notes/statphys). The density of states for an electron gas is calculated explicitly there, check out eqn. (5.21) and following. Then, some BEC calculations are made explicitly, starting on page 119. V is the (physical) volume of the system you look at.

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, depending on your previous exposure to statistical physics (or depending on whether I actually got your question ?! ;-))

Comment: it seems the link is broken